# Codename one:move hamberger menu below Title

Tags: codenameone

I want to show hamberger menu in container below Form Title .currently hamberger menu comes on Form Title by default .So can you please help me to resolve that.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To start, you need to hide the default Hamburger menu button. To do that, add this theme constant:

```
hideLeftSideMenuBool
```

and set it to `true`

Secondly, Create a custom button that has same `UIID` and `Icon` as the default one or other styling you want. Add this button to a container at the north of your `BorderLayout` form.

Finally, add below `actionListener` to the button:

```
final Button cmdMenuButton = new Button(" ", yourMenuIcon, "TitleCommand");
cmdMenuButton.addActionListener(evt -> myForm.getToolbar().openSideMenu());
```

Comment: error is  an internal application error occured. java.lang.NullPointerException